# Is it possible to create my own Publish Profile "Provider"?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget

Visual Studio supports several predefined **publish profile providers**. For easing our private upload to our internal **nuget server** I was curious if I can create some sort of **Pack&Publish To NUGET** in on single publish profile. Searching through the web and the documentation

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/visual-studio-publish-profiles?view=aspnetcore-6.0

or

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/ff398069(v=vs.110)

showed nothing that helped. Maybe it would be sufficient to simply do publish to a folder and execute nuget.exe from there.

I specifically want to do the job in the UI and not with commandline tools. I also wanted to avoid writing a Visual Studio extension for this.